# Imagebutton work like as back button in android

Tags: android

i m new to android and working on actionbar so the action contain two imagebutton and textview
here is the snapshot of actionbar:

[image]

the red mark is the imagebutton .

so the question is how can we move to the previous activity or screen on click or pressing the imagebutton as the default android back does or i had go for explicitly mentioning intent for it.

any help will be great.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In image button click just add `finish();` its take you in previous activity.

For **ActionBar**: if you are using it below way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

then you go in previous activity using below code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for more detail.

here is full code of image button:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add onclicklistener to the ImageButton, and call finish(); in the onClick() method:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most, **providing Back button in Android app is FAIL or Bad idea.**

Even though, if you want to implement Back button navigation then you can implement below things:

1. Override [**`onBackKeyPressed()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) and call `finish()` method inside it.
2. Call `finish()` method inside the button click listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have give you a code that should be work in action bar

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) 
{
     imageButton=(ImageButton)                     menu.findItem(R.id.overflow).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.imageOverflow);
}
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In image Button onclickListener just call finish() method.

ImageButton imagebtn_back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

imagebtn_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
```

});